# Android Device Not Passing HTML POST data to Default.aspx NameValueCollection?

Tags: c#, javascript, android, asp.net

I have to confess that I am extremely confused and I have searched for hours to try and resolve this issue. It's especially frustrating since it ONLY appears to affect Android devices - It works perfectly fine with Windows (Chrome, Safari, FireFox, IE), Mac, and iPhone. Here is the scenario:

I have a standard HTML page with some embedded javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
function doSubmit()
{
    // some processing occurs here then the form gets submitted
    document.myForm.submit();
}
</script>
. . .
<form id="myForm" 
    name="myForm" 
    action="/foo/bar/Default.aspx" 
    method="POST" 
    enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
    target="about:blank" 
    onsubmit="window.open('', this.target);" >
<!-- Data Entry Fields here... ->
. . .
<!-- Hidden Fields here... ->
<input type="hidden" id="value1" name="value1" />
<input type="hidden" id="value2" name="value2" />
<input type="hidden" id="value3" name="value3" />
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="doSubmit()" value="Click Me">
```

The Default.aspx is opened and the following checks occur:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;

        string frmValue1 = nvc["value1"];
        string frmValue2 = nvc["value2"];
        string frmValue3 = nvc["value3"];
        //
        if (frmValue1 == null)
            frmValue1 = "{Blank}";

        if (frmValue2 == null)
            frmValue2 = "{Blank}";

        if (frmValue3 == null)
            frmValue3 = "{Blank}";
        //
        sMsg = string.Concat(sMsg, string.Format("Value1: {0}", frmValue1), "|");
        sMsg = string.Concat(sMsg, string.Format("Value2: {0}", frmValue2), "|");
        sMsg = string.Concat(sMsg, string.Format("Value3: {0}", frmValue3), "|");
        //
        Response.Write(sMsg);
```

When the Default.aspx page is rendered on the Android devices, every single value comes back as `null` (printed as "{Blank}" on the page). I have also attempted to submit the form using the jQuery structured submit: `$("#myForm").submit();` but with the same results.

Any help that you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

TIA!

Comment: does it make any difference if you remove your event handlers? at least that would give you an indication of where the issue is. Also you might consider refactoring to only using the onsubmit event since the click triggers the submit anyway.

Comment: Actually, (confession time) the event handlers were moved up after a `Trim()` statement downstream caused an `NullReferenceException` to be thrown. Since the values were *always* populated with something in the `doSubmit()` function, the `try` block began much lower originally. I will try your other suggestion of refactoring and post my results.

Comment: Even by removing all javascripting and simply doing a standard POST, this is still failing. It is as if no data is being passed in. The `nvc.Count` property indicates 0. I also tried changing the encoding to `multipart/form` just to see if it made any difference - It did not.

Comment: Haven't tried name value collection myself, have you tested with form collection? From the looks of it you use it in the same way

Comment: Unfortunately, `Request.Form.Count == 0`. It really does behave as if the system isn't passing data with the POST.